# Evaluations of a Definite Integral with cosine function

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you evaluate this integral? Does it involve an elliptical integral? What technique do I use to evaluate this integral?

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 2\pi  }{ \sqrt { 5-4\cos { \theta  }  } d\theta  } $$

Comment: √[5-4 cos(theta)] is the function being integrated from 0 to 2pi.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha returns an answer that seems to require the elliptic integral of the second kind with parameter $m=k^2$.

Comment: Yeah, this is an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) and in general does not have a closed-form solution.  You're better off plugging this into a numeric integrator.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{eqnarray*} I = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{5-4\cos(2t)}\,dt &=& 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\cos^2 t+9\sin^2 t}\,dt\\&=&4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{9-8\cos^2 t}\,dt\\&=&12\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac{8}{9}\,\sin^2 t}\end{eqnarray*} $$
is twelve times a [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).